# PHP-FPM cannot change log file location

Tags: php

I am running a LAMP server (Almalinux) supporting different versions of php. I have used the remi repos to get the multiple php files setup.

looking at the main /etc/php-fpm.conf file, it writes errors to the standard /var/log location:

```
error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/error.log
```

- Which is fine.

The remi setup created /etc/opt/remi/php81/php-fpm.conf which specifies the location of the error log file. I added my own path to where I want the file written:

```
;error_log = /var/opt/remi/php81/log/php-fpm/error.log
error_log /var/log/php81-fpm/error.log
```

- now the service refuses to start, if I change it back it is fine. I have created that folder and even an empty error.log file (with the same permissions) but still it refuses to start.

```
php81-php-fpm.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Unit php81-php-fpm.service entered failed state.
```

The error log message, seems irrelevant to the issue:

```
ERROR: [/etc/opt/remi/php81/php-fpm.conf:455] value is NULL for a ZEND_INI_PARSER_ENTRY
```

For now, I have reverted, but I would like to understand what is going wrong. BTW I tried disabling selinux, but that had no effect either.

Comment: Looks like a SELinux issue,new directory must have httpd_log_t context

Answer (score 2):

Did you copy-and-paste that line or did you type it here by hand? Because you are  missing a "=" sign...

```
error_log = /var/log/php81-fpm/error.log
```

Comment: I can't believe it. Yes. I just forgot the =. It was there a some point, I must have deleted it before a save. After all the complexity of having 3 versions of php, getting Moodle working alongside WordPress sites. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Forgot to mention, if you do this you should edit the php81-php-fpm file in the logrotate.d folder, to ensure your logs get rotated as you would expect them to.